# Making Dovecot keep its TCP connections alive?

Tags: dovecot, imap, keepalive

I'm trying to run a benchmarking application which connects to my IMAP server and has a "warm up" phase during which IMAP connections are being established. I've set my limits properly and the mail server should be able to handle all the connection just fine (2GB memory, 50GB space, 2vCPUs).

However, this warmup phase takes a while. In the meantime, while all my tcp connections to dovecot are being established, the ones that are established first seem to be getting closed (or maybe I'm running out of sockets, but I've set all system limit *pretty* high).

Here's my dovecot log of this happening: http://pastebin.com/ZaSyDZVy

Could anyone advise how I could possible increase dovecot's *keep_alive* default? Or perhaps increase the maximum number of sockets it could use? I've checked all I could think of, but any suggestions at all would be quite welcome.

*Note*: I'm intenationally using plaintext authentication and IMAP only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LoginProcess says that if you have set `secure mode` via

```
service imap-login {
  service_count = 1
```

each client fork his own login process and then

> If the maximum login process count is reached, the oldest process in
>   logging-in state (ie. non-proxying) is destroyed.
>   That is intended to allow newly connected clients to get connection.

If you set up so called `hi performance mode` via

```
service imap-login {
  service_count = 0
```

then all incoming connections will be processed by one process - without limitations.